# Classificando li em uma div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal estou precisando de classificar alfabeticamente uma `div`, uso a seguinte estrategia, coloco em uma `div` com `display: none` todos os li, assim após se inseridos todos no `html`, eu faço o `while` para enquanto tiver `li` naquela `div` ele irá verificar qual é maior, o maior, identificando ele adiciona em outra `div`, que está como `display:block` após eu removo da `div` com `display:none` e fico neste loop.

O meu código está a seguir:

```
while($('#check_presencaNone li').length > '0'){
  $('#check_presencaNone li').each(function(i){
     if($(this).text().toUpperCase() < valor){
       valor = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
       ponteiro = $(this);
     }
  });
  ponteiro.clone().appendTo('#check_presenca');
  ponteiro.remove();   
  console.log($('#check_presencaNone li').length);
}
```

> Ao executar está ficando em um loop infinito, e não estou conseguindo identificar o erro. O que está errado ?

Comment: primeiro eu nao usaria assim '0' e sim sem as aspas ... como o length é int .... usar o 0 sem aspas tbm sera int. outra coisa ... nesse caso $('#check_presencaNone li').length voce precisa ir decrementando ele ne para chegar ao ponto dele zerar ..... da forma que esta ele vai loopar infinitamente mesmo

Comment: Como decremento ? Porque para mim o lenght resolveria, qual seria as edições proposta por você ?

Comment: Porque a ideia é que o remove, remova a linha que ja foi ordenada no caso. Preciso na verdade ordenar a div.

Comment: entendi mestre ... voce consegueria montar um exemplo funcionar para podermos ajudar ?

Comment: Xii, fica dificil porque é algo dinamico

Comment: Mais vou tentar.

Comment: eu entendo que é complicado montar um exemplo disso ... mas concordamos que sem isso tambem é complicado né, ter a visao do todo para tentar achar o problema

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a79vn0jx/ Está ai consegui

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34314/discussion-between-otto-and-renan-rodrigues).

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro ponto que resolveria sua questão seria alterar o codigo do while para o de baixo:

```
for(i = 0; i <= $('#check_presencaNone li').length; i++) {
  $('#check_presencaNone li').each(function(i){
     if($(this).text().toUpperCase() < valor){
       valor = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
       ponteiro = $(this);
     }
  });
  ponteiro.clone().appendTo('#check_presenca');
  ponteiro.remove();   
  console.log($('#check_presencaNone li').length);
}
```

Comment: Aproveitei para adicionar a resposta ao problema inicial

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade eu tinha algumas questões de lógica, juntamente com a resposta do nosso amigo @Otto cheguei a esta resolução.

Bastava para min, zerar o valor da variável `valor`, pois quando ele passava pela primeira vez e identificava o menor, ele selecionava o ponteiro, assim todo hora ele percorria o mesmo ponteiro para povoar a tela. então o código com a solução correta ficou assim.

```
var ponteiro = null,
valor = 'ZZZZZZZZ';
while( $('#check_presencaNone li').length > 0) {
 $('#check_presencaNone li').each(function(i){
   if($(this).text().toUpperCase() < valor){
      valor = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
      ponteiro = $(this);
   }
 });
 ponteiro.clone().appendTo('#check_presenca');
 ponteiro.remove();
 valor = 'ZZZZZZZZ';
}
```